# iOS - AWS SNS Endpoint setting to disabled

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swift, ios8, amazon-sns

I have been trying to understand how to create an app that will receive push notifications from an AWS SNS set up.

I have created the app certificates etc and from what I can see, things should work.
I have followed some tutorials and also managed to get my iOS app to receive push notifications sent to APNS from a PHP script run locally on my dev machine.

The thing I appear to be missing is that when I try to set up my AWS SNS app to publish a message to my development device endpoint, it changes the state from Enabled to disabled without any reasoning or error messages coming from the AWS console.

My understanding is that the device token I am using is correct as the PHP script works, my certificates etc are working as this would mean the PHP script would not work and that I must be missing something between the AWS setup and iOS set up.

Some Code:

**iOS Setup - works as notifications received from PHP script**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.EUWest1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager()
        .setDefaultServiceConfiguration(defaultServiceConfiguration)

    let notTypes:UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    let noteSettings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notTypes, categories: nil)

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(noteSettings)

    return true        

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    println("hello from user")
}


func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    println("recieve!!")
}
```

**AWS Screenshot**
[image]

If anyone can think of or notice something I am missing here it would be greatly helpful in my learning process!

Comment: Any help on this. I have re created my certificate, updated credentials on my application and tried my level best on making it happen, but yet again the endpoint gets disabled. Please let me know anything about how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that it's a certificate issue.  Try creating and using a new one.  I had similar problems that ended up being resolved by generating a new certificate (despite the old one working in a third-party test tool).

Comment: I did make a new one and it still remains. What should I do?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: If you're still having this problem despite successfully [testing your certificate manually](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher), you might try uploading your project's source code where people can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem. I had all of the setup correct, but I missed enabling the remote notification entitlement in the plist. Once I enabled this, the problem was rectified.